# Error 438 when I try and work between two different workbooks. Specifically, I want to print the row count from one in the other

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks, called "Sales" and "Tracker" respectively. I want to print the no. of rows in "Sales" in the workbook "Tracker".

"Tracker" just has one sheet: "Count." "Sales has two": "Data" and "Data 2". I want to print the no. of rows in "Data" onto the "Tracker" workbook.

Here's the code, which yields error 438:

```
Sub StoreDate()
    Dim SalesWb As Workbook, TrackerWb As Workbook
    Set SalesWb = Workbooks("Sales.xlsm")
    Set TrackerWb = Workbooks("Tracker.xlsm")

    Dim SalesWs As Worksheet, TrackerWs As Worksheet
    Set SalesWs = SalesWb("Data")
    Set TrackerWs = TrackerWb("Count")

    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = SalesWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    TrackerWs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = last_row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference the sheets in the workbooks you need to use Worksheets (or Sheets if you are being lazy).

```vb
Sub StoreDate()
    Dim SalesWb As Workbook, TrackerWb As Workbook
    Set SalesWb = Workbooks("Sales.xlsm")
    Set TrackerWb = Workbooks("Tracker.xlsm")

    Dim SalesWs As Worksheet, TrackerWs As Worksheet
    Set SalesWs = SalesWb.Worksheets("Data")
    Set TrackerWs = TrackerWb.Worksheets("Count")

    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = SalesWs.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    TrackerWs.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = last_row
End Sub
```